# run function after textfield fill

Tags: actionscript-3

Hi I'm just learning actionscript and have been trying to get a button to run a function after a textfield has been filled in. phoneNum is the textfield ID.

```
//function with var testing the textfield content. 

function sendInfoBtn()
    {
    var lengthOf = phoneNum.text.length;
    if (lengthOf == 10){
    sendInfo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doThisThing, false, 0, true);
    }
}

//I'd really like to just add the lengthOf variable to this changelistener somehow
phoneNum.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, sendInfoBtn, false, 0, true);

function realFunction(){
//things to do
}
```

Comment: put `var lengthOf` outside of the `sendInfoBtn` function so it will be more global

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner approach would be :

```
sendInfo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doThisThing, false, 0, true);

private function doThisThing(e:MouseEvent):void
{
   if(phoneNum.text.length >= 10) 
   {
      realFunction();
   }
}
```

This way you don't need the change event, once the user clicks the button just validate if the text field has enough characters and call the actual function that you want.

If you want the button to be disabled until enough characters are entered then you can use the CHANGE event :

```
sendInfo.enabled = false;
phoneNum.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, phoneNumChange, false, 0, true);

sendInfo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doThisThing, false, 0, true);

private function doThisThing(e:MouseEvent):void
{
   if(phoneNum.text.length >= 10) 
   {
      realFunction();
   }
}

private function phoneNumChange(e:Event):void
{  
    sendInfo.enabled = phoneNumb.text.length >= 10;
}
```

Comment: And potentially additionally use the change event to enable/disable the button based on the length of the textfield, for usability purposes.

Comment: yes @stefan thats what i want to do is disable the button until the field is full... using change event how could I code that??

Also, I'm getting an error on the function call.. the function has arguments... do I need them to run it?

    'function realFunction(btnId:String)'

Answer (score 0):

From the comment above I assume the question was how to enable/disable a button based on the state of an input field.

Here is some code that should illustrate it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

        private function onPhoneNumChanged():void
        {
            sendButton.enabled = (phoneNumField.text.length == 10);
        }

        private function onSend():void
        {
            // do send the phone number
        }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <mx:VBox>

        <s:TextInput id="phoneNumField" change="onPhoneNumChanged();"/>

        <s:Button label="SEND" id="sendButton" enabled="false" click="onSend();"/>

    </mx:VBox>

</s:Application>
```